# スプライトノードが消えない理由がわからない

Tags: ios, spritekit

何回か、質問させていただいて改善してみたのですが、下のほうにあるタッチイベントでスプライトノードが消えません。
printは実行されているのですが、ノードをタッチしてみても消えません。
どなたか、解決方法をお知りの方はご助力お願いします。

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit


class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var moveToAction :SKAction!
//    ランダムを使う準備
    let randomSource = GKARC4RandomSource()

    var mySprite : SKSpriteNode!
    var mySprite2 : SKSpriteNode!
    var mySprite3 : SKSpriteNode!
    var mySprite4: SKSpriteNode!
    var mySprite5 : SKSpriteNode!
    var mySprite6 : SKSpriteNode!
    var mySprite7 : SKSpriteNode!
    var mySprite8 : SKSpriteNode!

     override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        //        画像からスプライトを作成する
        let mySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "kuri_2.png")
        //        サイズプロパティでサイズを設定
        mySprite.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        //        ポジションプロパティで設定
        // 画像の描画場所を指定.
        mySprite.position = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 0)
//        初期速度を設定する
        mySprite.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(10.0, 10.0)
        // 摩擦係数を０に設定.
        mySprite.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0



        addChild(mySprite)


//        たくさんの敵をつくります
        let mySprite2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "kuri_2.png")
        mySprite2.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        mySprite2.position  = CGPoint(x: -100, y: 500)
        addChild(mySprite2)

        let mySprite3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "kuri_2.png")
        mySprite3.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        mySprite3.position  = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        addChild(mySprite3)

        let mySprite4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "kuri_2.png")
        mySprite4.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        mySprite4.position  = CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 1000)
        addChild(mySprite4)

        let mySprite5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "kuri_2.png")
        mySprite5.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        mySprite5.position  = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 1000)
        addChild(mySprite5)

        let mySprite6 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "kuri_2.png")
        mySprite6.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        mySprite6.position  = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1000)
        addChild(mySprite6)

        let mySprite7 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "kuri_2.png")
        mySprite7.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        mySprite7.position  = CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 500)
        addChild(mySprite7)

        let mySprite8 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "kuri_2.png")
        mySprite8.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        mySprite8.position  = CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 0)
        addChild(mySprite8)








        //        回転の動きをいれる
        let action1 = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(360 * M_PI / 180), duration: 1)
        let action3 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(action1)

//        ランダムな秒数待つ動き
        let wait1 = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0, withRange: 2.0)
//        ランダムな秒数で動き出す
        let randomSec = Double(randomSource.nextIntWithUpperBound(30)) / 10.0 + 3.0

        //        指定した位置まで移動させる
        let action4 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: 512, y: 380), duration: randomSec)

                //        複数の動きを同時に処理
        let actionx = SKAction.group([action1,action3,action4,wait1])
        //        これらの処理をリピートさせる
        let actionR = SKAction.repeatActionForever(actionx)


//        それぞれの出現時間を変えたい
        let action2y = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0,withRange: 10.0)
        let action2x = SKAction.sequence([action2y, actionx,actionR])

        let action3y = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0,withRange: 10.0)
        let action3x = SKAction.sequence([action3y, actionx,actionR])

        let action4y = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0,withRange: 10.0)
        let action4x = SKAction.sequence([action4y, actionx,actionR])

        let action5y = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0,withRange: 10.0)
        let action5x = SKAction.sequence([action5y, actionx,actionR])

        let action6y = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0,withRange: 10.0)
        let action6x = SKAction.sequence([action6y, actionx,actionR])

        let action7y = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0,withRange: 10.0)
        let action7x = SKAction.sequence([action7y, actionx,actionR])

        let action8y = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0,withRange: 10.0)
        let action8x = SKAction.sequence([action8y, actionx,actionR])






        //        動きをつけます
        mySprite.runAction(actionx)
        mySprite2.runAction(action2x)
        mySprite3.runAction(action3x)
        mySprite4.runAction(action4x)
        mySprite5.runAction(action5x)
        mySprite6.runAction(action6x)
        mySprite7.runAction(action7x)
        mySprite8.runAction(action8x)


//        センターの栗をつくる
        let centerKuri = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "kuri_5.png")
        centerKuri.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        centerKuri.position =  CGPointMake(self.size.width/2.0,self.size.height/2.0)

        addChild(centerKuri)

//        クリスマスツリーをつくる
        let tree = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "sozai.png")
        tree.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
        tree.position =  CGPointMake(self.size.width/2.0,self.size.height/1.5)

        addChild(tree)



    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        // マルチタッチを有効にする
        self.view?.multipleTouchEnabled = true

        // 一つの情報を取り出します
        for touch in touches {
            // シーン上の位置をとりだします
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            // その位置にあるノードをしらべる
            let touchNodes = self.nodesAtPoint(location)
            // ノードひとつひとつを調べる
            for tNode in touchNodes {
                // タッチしたノードが敵なら消す
                // mySpriteを削除.
                if tNode == ([mySprite,mySprite2,mySprite3,mySprite4,mySprite5,mySprite6,mySprite7,mySprite8]){
                    removeChildrenInArray([mySprite,mySprite2,mySprite3,mySprite4,mySprite5,mySprite6,mySprite7,mySprite8]) }
                print(tNode)

            }
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */

            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for tNode in touchNodes {
    // タッチしたノードが敵なら消す
    // mySpriteを削除.
    if tNode == ([mySprite,mySprite2,mySprite3,mySprite4,mySprite5,mySprite6,mySprite7,mySprite8]) {
    removeChildrenInArray([mySprite,mySprite2,mySprite3,mySprite4,mySprite5,mySprite6,mySprite7,mySprite8])
    }
    print(tNode)
}
```

`SKNode`（`SKSpriteNode`）のインスタンスと、`SKNode`をメンバーとする配列を“比較”しても、意味ありませんよね？
配列のメンバーのどれかと、`tNode`が一致するかを調べないと、だめですよね？

```
for tNode in touchNodes {
    let enemyArray = [mySprite,mySprite2,mySprite3,mySprite4,mySprite5,mySprite6,mySprite7,mySprite8]
    // タッチしたノードが敵なら消す
    // mySpriteを削除.
    if enemyArray.contains(tNode) {
        tNode.removeFromParent()
    }
    print(tNode)
}
```

注：
`Array`のメソッド`contains()`は、iOS 9から有効（Available）です。Appleのドキュメントに直接あたらず、ネット上の日本語の情報だけ探していたら、見つけにくかったかもしれません。そして、iOS 8まで考慮したプロジェクトを製作しているなら、別の方法を考えなければいけません。